# Microsoft Cognitive Services Recommedations

Tags: recommendation-engine, azure-cognitive-services

I try to use Microsoft Cognitive Services Recommedations. I successfully create model and upload a catalog file to a model. But i can't upload usage file. But i received error 
`400 - {"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"(EXT-0108) Passed argument is invalid.","innerError":{"message":"'1' errors detected in the first '1' lines of the file","innerError":{"message":"Invalid user ID format
"}}}}`

Sample of the usage file:

0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277cd7,2015/06/10T01:08:14
0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277c94,2015/06/10T01:02:47
0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277c9c,2015/06/10T01:01:34
0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277cbf,2015/06/10T00:57:31
0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277cba,2015/06/10T00:56:00
0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277cf2,2015/06/10T00:50:44
0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277cdd,2015/06/10T00:49:34
0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277ca4,2015/06/10T00:49:01
0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277cc0,2015/06/10T00:47:44
0003BFFDC7118D12,58152c638b48593df4277cec,2015/06/10T00:45:32

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like one of either of these two things is happening:

1. Your userID: 0003BFFDC7118D12 isn't valid
2. The file-header is being read as the first line, and you should build your own .csv file to compensate.